# Variance property

Tags: statistics, covariance, variance

I know that $$Var(X + Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2Cov(X,Y)$$

Now if I applied that same rule to $Var(\beta Y + (1-\beta)C)$ would we have $$Var(\beta Y + (1-\beta)C) = \beta^2 Var(Y) + (1-\beta)^{2}Var(C) + 2(1-\beta)Cov(Y,C)$$

I am not sure if this is correct any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The last term should be $ +2\beta (1-\beta)Cov(Y, C)$.

Comment: The correct should be $$Var(\beta Y + (1-\beta)C) = \beta^2 Var(Y) + (1-\beta)^{2}Var(C) + 2\beta(1-\beta)Cov(Y,C)$$

Comment: You need to define which symbols are parameters, and which are random variables.

Comment: It's always a good idea when you have derived a formula to test it for some simple cases where you know the answer. For example if $\beta = 1$ the left hand side is $\text{Var}(Y)$ which agrees with the right hand side. If $\beta = 0$ then the left hand side  is $\text{Var}(C)$ while the right hand side is $\text{Var}(C) + 2\text{Cov}(Y,C)$ so your formula cannot be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ramil pointed out in the comment section, the correct answer would be:

$$
Var(\beta Y + (1-\beta)C) = \beta^2Var(Y) + (1-\beta)^2Var(C) + 2\beta(1-\beta)Cov(Y, C)
$$

I just want to add a tip so that it's easier for you to expand the variance of a sum better in the future. Think of it as similar to the popular property:

$(a + b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$

and it should show you how to treat the constant in the variance case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check out the definition of variance and covariance; then it will be crystal clear.

However,
note that
$$
cov(\beta Y, (1-\beta)C) = E(\beta Y - E(\beta Y))((1-\beta)C - E((1-\beta)C)) = \beta(1-\beta)cov(Y,C).
$$